# How would i add the corresponding values of a list together when in string form?

Tags: python, list

Say if I had:

```
code = 'aaaa'
numbercode = '1234'
Lcode = list(code)
Lnumbercode = list(numbercode)
```

And what I want is :

```
a+1
a+2
a+3
a+4
```

Comment: Do ```code``` and ```numbercode``` always have the same number of letters?

Comment: i actually want it for 8 characters but thought it would be easier just typing 4

Comment: But will they both always be 8, or could one be 7 or 9 or 56 sometimes?

Comment: This isn't worth making an answer, but `'a+' + '\na+'.join(map(str,range(8)))`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip` to iterate over both the iterables simultaneously:

```
In [21]: ['%s+%s'%(i, j) for i, j in zip(code, numbercode)]
Out[21]: ['a+1', 'a+2', 'a+3', 'a+4']
```

or you can use `map` and `lambda` as @wnnmaw mentioned, while this would raise `TypeError` if `code` and `numbercode` are of different length:

```
In [24]: map(lambda x,y: x+"+"+y, code, numbercode)
Out[24]: ['a+1', 'a+2', 'a+3', 'a+4']
```

Comment: what is the 21 in brackets?

Comment: @user3382238 it's the prompt of `ipython` shell, just like `>>>` in cmdline python ;)

Comment: I'm going to put this here, since it's no better than your answer, but it could be done with ```map(lambda x,y: x+"+"+y, list(code), list(numbercode))``` if you're fond of ```lambda``` and ```map```

Comment: Its also worth nothing that the comprehension can handle different sized input by just excluding any extras whereas ```map``` will break with a ```TypeError```

Answer (score 2):

```
map('+'.join, zip(code, numbercode))
```

Comment: Note: this only works if the two iterables are of equal length. If they are not, a `TypeError` will be produced.

Comment: @AlexThornton `zip` will truncate the longer sequence to the length of the shorter sequence, no `TypeError` raised. However, if `numbercode=[1,2,3,4]`, `join` will not be able to operate on an int.

Comment: @IceArdor true, but `numbercode` isn't that, so we don't have to worry. :)